# Make a request to StackExchange Api

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc-5, stackexchange-api

I'm trying to request list of tags on StackExchange in JSON format by [url](http://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/tags?order=desc&sort=popular&site=stackoverflow), but problem is, that I'm getting some broken text instead of JSON, so I can't even parse it.

**P.S.** Done it with the help of RestSharp.

```
private void Refresh()
    {
        var client = new RestClient("http://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/tags?order=desc&sort=popular&site=stackoverflow");

        var result = client.Execute(new RestRequest(Method.GET));

        var array = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(result.Content);

        Platforms = array.Platforms;
    }
```

Comment: Please [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/29486722/edit) and include the **broken text**.

Comment: I don't use c# but I've dabbled with the stackexchange api, and from what I experienced, the response is gzip encoded. With the Java client I used, I had to use a gzip decoder

Comment: Don't deface your question when you found the answer. Please [post an answer with your solution](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/29486722/3).

Answer (score 2):

If you make GET request to this URL using [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler), you will see that response has a header:

```
Content-Encoding: gzip
```

Which means that response is compressed with gzip. Good news is that `HttpWebRequest` can handle that:

```
request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.Deflate | DecompressionMethods.GZip;
```

After you add this row you will get nice and readable JSON.

Comment: Idk why, but didn't work for me. I used RestSharp and now it's okay. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I have tested this with your code and it worked. But anyway, I think it's good idea to use RestSharp.

Answer (score 0):

As @peeskillet mentions, this looks like compressed data. Please have a look at 
[What is the canonical method for an HTTP client to instruct an HTTP server to disable gzip responses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13753665/what-is-the-canonical-method-for-an-http-client-to-instruct-an-http-server-to-di) and especially [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14427083/2298807).

Something like

```
Accept-Encoding: *;q=0
```

should help.